# Python import own module - name not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to update my basic jumble game. I already did that the script gets words from a text file, now I want to separate them into modules as I have different text files with different words.

I have my main script, jumble_game.py:

```
import random
import amazement

#Welcome the player
print("""
    Welcome to Word Jumble.
        Unscramble the letters to make a word.
""")

def wordlist(file):
    with open(file) as afile:
        global the_list
        the_list = [word.strip(",") for line in afile for word in line.split()]
    print(the_list)

def main():
    score = 0
    for i in range(4):
        word = random.choice(the_list)
        theWord = word
        jumble = ""
        while(len(word)>0):
            position = random.randrange(len(word))
            jumble+=word[position]
            word=word[:position]+word[position+1:]
        print("The jumble word is: {}".format(jumble))

        #Getting player's guess
        guess = input("Enter your guess: ").lower()

        #congratulate the player
        if(guess==theWord):
            print("Congratulations! You guessed it")
            score +=1

        else:
            print ("Sorry, wrong guess.")
    print("You got {} out of 10".format(score))

#filename = "words/amazement_words.txt"
wordlist(filename)
main()
```

I want the file amazement.py to be imported into jumble_game.py because I want the user to select the group, from which the words will be chosen.

amazement.py:

```
filename = "amazement_words.txt"
```

I get this error:

```
File "jumble_game.py", line 49, in <module>
    wordlist(filename)
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

If I do it the other way, importing the main script into amazement.py and run the latter, the code functions without a problem.

Any clue what am I missing? Still a Python beginner so bear with me. :)

Thanks for help/suggestions!

Comment: Why not use `amazement.filename`?

Comment: Or `from amazement import *` should allow you to access `filename` without the `amazement` prefix.

Comment: It works, perfect, thank you.  But later I will have also a sad.py with words from another text file. Is it better to use `from ... import *` ?

Comment: As I understand it, I will have to do an input menu from which the user could select the group(module), from which the words will be chosen. If I do it with if statements, should I include the `import` in there as in this example?

`def menu():
    print '1. Go opA'
    print '2. Go opB'
    print '3. Exit'
    pick    = raw_input('Pick one: ')

    if pick == '1':
        import opa
        opa.menu()
    elif pick == '2':
        import opb
        opb.menu()
    else:
        import sys
        sys.exit()

menu()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you've stated is a standard namespace/scope problem. You've created a variable within the scope of amazement.py, but not in the jumble_game.py namespace. As a result, you can't access the top level variable in amazement.py without telling your program from where to get that variable.

You can do a few things. I'll list two:

1.

`from amazement import filename`

This will allow you to use the term "filename" as you've described.

or 2.

Replace any reference to `filename` with `amazement.filename`.

You can read more about scopes and namespace here: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html